# Blackberry Application not deploying in simulator from eclipse

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-simulator

I wrote a first sample Hello World Program for BB in eclipse using the plugin and everything worked fine. But then I wrote another app, not much different from the first and I went to deploy it and the simulator opened but only the first application was there. I tried loading the .cod file from inside the simulator but that didn't work either. I also tried exiting and resetting the simulator and using the clean.bat file but none of that worked either. Finally I tried to load another sample program I downloaded from RIM and that worked just fine. Help! I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess rapc failed to execute. Can you check your console output for something that goes like "rapc failed to execute for this project because of XYZ"

If this isn't the case, one thing that worked for me was creating a new workspace, project and copying just the source files to that directory and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking there could be 2 things happening.

1. The most likely is that there's some error in your program that is preventing it from compiling.  Check the problems tab to see if there's anything there.
2. If you look at the toolbar under BlackBerry -> Build Configurations there are 3 options "Private", "Debug", and "Release".  This allows you to choose which projects to compile.  Edit whichever one you're using to make sure your project is selected.